# PHP include_path doesn't work

Tags: php, debian

I have the documents at `http://www.example.com/` in `/home/www/example.com/www` running on Debian Squeeze.

```
/home/www/example.com/
    www/
         index.php
    php/
         include_me.php
```

In the php.ini I've uncommented and changed to:

```
include_path =".:/home/www/example.com"
```

In a script index.php in www, I have `require_once("/php/include_me.php")`. The output I am getting from PHP is:

```
Warning: require_once(/php/include_me.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/example.com/www/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/php/include_me.php' (include_path='.:/home/www/example.com') in /home/www/example.com/www/index.php on line 2
```

As you can see, the include-path is set correctly according to the error. But if I do `require_once("../php/include_me.php");`, it works. Therefore, something has to be wrong with the include-path.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once("/php/include_me.php")
```

That is wrong (in your particular case). Right now you've told PHP to search for `include_me.php` file in `/php/` folder (yep, `/php/` and not `/home/www/example.com/php/` as you expecting as you have provided **absolute** and not relative path).

Remove leading slash and enjoy:

```
require_once("php/include_me.php")
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php